# Is it possible to share Hyper-V Manager

Tags: windows-8, windows-authentication, hyper-v

I have a test environment that I host from my computer. I have configured an external switch so that it can be accessed by others.

If we take a look inside the Hyper-V Manager we can see that we have: "**Hyper-V Manager**" and under it we have connection to the **local machine**. We also have the possibility to add a new connection by *connecting a server*.

[image]

So can I host my PC's **Hyper-V Instance** as a server in the domain and would that make my peers able to connect to it as a new instance in their Hyper-V Manager?

Is it possible to share Hyper-V Manager or my instance of it, so that other people can use snapshots and the other functions that Hyper-V manager have to offer?

I'm thankful for all help!

Comment: More info about your system (Windows version, Hyper-V version) and user rights may help.

Comment: Admin, please move this question to serverfault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible for other users to manage your machines Hyper-V instance with Hyper-V Manager run on a different machine, as long as they have the correct privileges. Which I believe it's up to you or the domain admin to set.

Check out [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2008/01/17/allowing-non-administrators-to-control-hyper-v.aspx) if it may help you. Good luck!